# Why is MapReduce failing/timing out?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, socket-timeout-exception

I am getting this error when running mapreduce example app in yarn and wondering if anyone can help me solve this problem

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the ports 45977,47920 are opened and hadoop slaves mentioned in the screenshot are reachable.